# PHP file_get_contents and domxpath UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, file-get-contents, domxpath

I'm reading an external file which contains this :

```
<td>ÖZGÜR&nbsp;</td>
```

And I read it like this :

```
$html = file_get_contents("");
$html = str_replace("charset=iso8859-9" , "charset=utf-8" , $html);
$rows = $x->query('//tr[contains(@class,"tablerow")]');
foreach($rows as $node)
{
  echo $node->childNodes->item(12)->nodeValue;
}
```

it does not echo `ÖZGÜR` , but it echoes `�ZGÜR`.

what type of encoding function should I call here ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

you should use

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

function to change the encoding instead of

$html = str_replace("charset=iso8859-9" , "charset=utf-8" , $html);

if data is stored in database than you need to change the connection encoding at the time of data fetching.

mysql_set_charset('utf8',$constring) than you will be able to retrieve in the UTF-8 format

Comment: I did, now the echo became `ÖZGÃœR`. Strangely, it saves to database correctly, but it converts İ to Ý

Answer (score 0):

Try converting $html to utf8 after you set it with file_get_contents, something like

```
$html = iconv('ISO-8859-9', 'UTF-8', $html);
```